# handle fill_parent and match_parent for different versions

Tags: android, gridview

How in my application can i handle different layout files for devices with target less than or equal to 2.1 and greater than 2.1.

Actually i have a gridview on which i have used fill-parent for both height and width. All works fine except when i run it on devices with target > 2.1, the scrollbars doesn't work and gridview doesn't scroll. 
But, replacing fill-parent wid match_parent makes it work in those devices, but doesn't even allow to compile when targeting devices <=2.1.

How can i handle this thing. its drivin' me nuts!

plz help...

Comment: match_parent is not defined before 2.1, so just use fill_parent instead of it, look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: @AnandTiwari : ok...got it...thnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)

fill_parent: The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent

so use fill_parent it will work for all.